# View a set of more divs on click without a unique ID/container

Tags: jquery, class, html, view, onclick

Here's a very primitive solution I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/pjD2n/1/

As you can see in the HTML comment, the problem is it will expand even after all divs are shown. I think manipulating the display value of the divs may be a more effective solution. The problem with this is, they do not have a unique ID... Also the certain divs must be initially visible by default.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/v6qqv/

Comment: YES. Perfect. So simple... thank you so much.

Comment: Undefined, would it be possible for a solution to this while the divs (.item) are positioned absolutely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/ to address divs in order of their index... also use show() and hide() function

Comment: would it be possible for a solution to this while the divs (.item) are positioned absolutely?